# asp:TextBox and MaxLength

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, textarea

I wrote this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSMSMessaggio" CssClass="inputForm" MaxLength="240" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

but on client side I can't see the attribute maxlength (which I need). Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: edit: I see what you mean, vote revoked!

Comment: @RGraham: no that's another kind of question. I want that attributes appair on client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use a `<textarea>` tag and add `runat="server"`?

```
<textarea id="txtSMSMessaggio" class="inputForm" maxlength="240" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Comment: No, because I can't use that textarea as controls in the .cs. Such as txtSMSMessaggio.Text

Comment: Declaring a `<textarea>` with a `runat=server` attribute will give you access to a [HtmlTextArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltextarea.aspx) in the code-behind. Not a 1-to-1 map, but still gives you access to the control.

Comment: You need to use [txtSMSMessaggio.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltextarea.value.aspx) instead

Answer (score 1):

you might not be interested in counting the characters in the TextBox, but its helpful to let the end user know there is a limit before it is reached.
you can do something like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var Maxlength = 240;
function taLimit() {
 var srcObject = event.srcElement;
 if (srcObject.value.length == Maxlength * 1) return false;
}

function taCount(tagName) {
 var srcObject = event.srcElement;
 if (srcObject.value.length > Maxlength * 1) srcObject.value = srcObject.value.substring(0, Maxlength * 1);
 if (tagName) visCnt.innerText = Maxlength - srcObject.value.length;
}
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSMSMessaggio" CssClass="inputForm" TextMode ="MultiLine" runat="server" 
onkeypress="return taLimit()" onkeyup="return taCount(Counter)" onfocus="return
taCount(Counter)" ></asp:TextBox><br />
(<span id="Counter">240</span> characters left)<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Regular Expression to restrict the user to 240 characters:-

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="txtSMSMessaggio"
ControlToValidate="txtInput"
ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,240}$"
ErrorMessage="Some error message"
Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```